# Hash numbers in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in table

**table1**

```
user_id
123456
123457
123458
123459
123460
```

I need to generate secure and 1 way hashed values which is 12 digits, non-sequential, no continuous zeros in the number. The hashed value should not overlap (means unique) and should ONLY be a NUMERIC. Something like:

**table1**

```
user_id     updated_user_id
123456      356456456345
123457      312412012412
123458      340475434545
123459      355344356461
123460      576898973434
```

I am aware of `ORA_HASH`, however it only outputs max 10 digits and I would like 12 digits.

Is there a way in Oracle SQL to achieve this?

Comment: Forget Oracle for a moment - is there any [common has function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) that can match those requirements?It seems very unlikely, not least because they seem arbitrary and unhelpful - what's the benefit of the *hash* being non-sequential or not having repeated zeros? (Some of your example outputs have sequential runs - the first contains 456 twice and 345 - or is that not what you meant?). If that's really what you want then you'll have to design your own algorithm, and then implement it in SQL or PL/SQL.

Comment: Following on from the excellent points raised by @alexpoole, what is your purpose in hashing these numbers? If it's for any form of security you should really think hard about your requirements. Because they aren't going to deliver strong encryption. 12 digits is too small a space to guarantee no hash collisions. Rolling your own hashing algorithm to handle that and the other constraints is weaker than using Oracle built-in features.

Comment: @APC - thank you for your suggestions. I'm looking at security. What would be the best way to do it? Should I use more digits? What is the best mechanism to ensure the user ID is secured?

Comment: @dang: what exactly does "secured" mean with regards to an ID? Why is `576898973434` "more secure" than 7654398? If you want some random unique IDs to prevent e.g. guessing of IDs then use a UUID. But if "guessing" a valid ID is a problem for your application, then the security in your application  that controls access to information connected to that user has serious problems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - how can I use UUID to generate unique 12 digit number in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Well as APC has pointed out 12 digits is to short anyway and doesn't give you any "security" at all. Either do it right, or stick with the IDs you have. It's probably more secure to never expose those IDs outside of your application.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - what length would be right to be secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be careful about adding hash values.  This can affect collisions.  So:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET updated_user_id = (ORA_HASH(user_id, 1000000000, 0) - 1) * 1000 +
                           ORA_HASH(user_id, 1000, 1) - 1;
```

You should realize that hash values can have collisions.  So, this is not 100% certain that the results will be unique.  If guaranteed uniqueness is important you might want to combine a hash with some manipulation of the user id -- arithmetic or bitwise operations.

Comment: Uniqueness is very important in generating. How can I use hash but make sure that it is unique?

Comment: @dang . . . You haven't provided enough information in your question to answer this.  It depends on what the purpose of the hashing is -- is it mean to be strong encryption or merely obfuscation?  How many different user ids are there?  Do they change over time?  I would suggest that you ask another question with more details.

Comment: The purpose is obfuscation, so that if someone hacks into the database, he should not be able to identify the user ID. We have over 100 million user IDs in the system which are sent by a customer. We want to change the user IDs, so they cannot construct it back. I will ask another question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET updated_user_id = 
    (
        ORA_HASH(user_id, 999999999, 0) * 1000 +
        ORA_HASH(user_id, 999999999, 1)
    );
```

As both hash functions use a different seed, 0 and 1, this should meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about security. So let's see what we can read from the IDs...

Let's say we know that user IDs 123456 and 123460 exist. Then we can surmise the following:

1. User IDs 123457, 123458, and 123459 also exist. We don't know, however, whether these users are still active or not.
2. User 123457 was entered after user 123456 and before user 123458.

I think that's about it. We've extracted all the secrets we were so terribly curious about.

If that's it, then you can apply some stupid algorithm. Here are some generated User IDs:

```
118233146610
414263244517
517233547579
618263344516
919293149578
```

12-digit numbers. To see the original numbers, look at every other digit: 118233146610 becomes 123460. So in order to generate the numbers get some random digits and use string manipulation to insert them. And unlike with hash numbers, there can be no duplicates.

Comment: I'd google Oracle + random and Oracle + sub string and Oracle and string concatenation :-)

Answer (score -2):

Add 110000000000 to each ORA_HASH.

Comment: ORA_HASH does not guarantee - no continuous zeroes.